# How does the "conditional or" (also called "short-circuit or"), written as `||` operator work in R?

Tags: r

So, how does the "conditional or" (also called "short-circuit or"), written as `||` operator work in R?

Querying [`?Logic`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/Logic) reveals:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate
>   for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

Sounds standard.

```
> library(dplyr)
> as_tibble(mtcars) %>% filter(between(hp,50,70))
# A tibble: 5 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
2  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
3  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
4  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
5  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
```

Ok.

```
> as_tibble(mtcars) %>% filter(between(hp,80,90))
# A tibble: 0 x 11
# … with 11 variables: mpg <dbl>, cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, ...
#   carb <dbl>
```

Ok. Let's try the standard or `|`, which is equivalent to set union here:

```
> as_tibble(mtcars) %>% filter(between(hp,50,70) | between(hp,80,90))
# A tibble: 5 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
2  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
3  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
4  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
5  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
```

Ok. Let's try the conditional or `||`, which should give the same result (`||` should never change semantics, only computation efficiency, except in the border case of partial function etc.):

```
> as_tibble(mtcars) %>% filter(between(hp,50,70) || between(hp,80,90))
# A tibble: 0 x 11
# … with 11 variables: mpg <dbl>, cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, ...
#   carb <dbl>
```

What is this weirdness? `between(hp,50,70) || between(hp,80,90)` yields TRUE nowhere?

Comment: `||` is not vectorised

Comment: @HongOoi ... and this means? It's grabbing the whole table once?

Comment: Got it, so it's not a "short-circuiting or" ... rather than a "shaving-off or". Language designers should have chosen a different string than `||` ... `|:`. Actually R can only have short-circuiting operator short-circuiting on NA -- as a final "NA" can ruin everything.

Comment: The "short-circuiting" refers to `||` and `&&` not evaluating the RHS if the LHS is sufficient to determine the outcome. This can be useful for control flow; for example `x <- NULL; if (is.null(x) || x < 0) cat("Got through!\n")` would give an error if you were to use `|` in the if-statement.

Comment: I am not sure why || would ever by used in dplyr function? Wouldn't it be best to give an error message since this behavior is completely unexpected by anybody who has used another language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `||` operator only compares the first elements of vectors, and returns a single logical result, while `|` compares vectors elementwise, and returns a vector result. See, e.g.:

```r
x <- c(FALSE, TRUE)
y <- c(FALSE, FALSE)

x | y
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
x || y
#> [1] FALSE
```

This is actually also mentioned in the help text you quoted: “The longer form evaluates left to right *examining only the first element of each vector.*” [emphasis added]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ok, but how does this apply in the above case exactly? I would think every `between` condition yields a vector of length 1 on each tibble row, and the two vectors would then be processed completely equivalently by `|` or `||`?

Comment: The operation in `filter()` is not processed separately for each row. When you refer to a column name in a tibble, you get a vector, and all operations are vector operations.

Comment: Columns being vectors is what allows you to write, for example, `mtcars %>% filter(mpg > mean(mpg))`

Comment: So the idea is that two (temporary) vectors (say, _v1_, _v2_) with booleans holding the result of the two `between`s are created. `|` will then create a third vector that is the result of pairwise _or_, and _filter_ will use that to generate the result case-by-case, whereas `||` will create a single vector of size 1 that holds TRUE if (completely arbitrarily) the first case gave at least one _between_ results of TRUE, and FALSE otherwise. So, with `||`, _filter_ will output either the whole input table or an empty table.